# Вставка слова. Не набирает 100 баллов

Tags: c

Задана строка слов D; слово – это последовательность символов, не содержащая
пробела. Слова разделяются ровно одним пробелом, последним словом является ″*″.
Найти первое совпадение слова W в строке слов D, вставить после него слово T и вывести
новую строку. Гарантируется, что в строке D есть хотя бы одно вхождение слова W.

Input
Со стандартного устройства ввода в первой строке вводится набор слов D, разделенных
ровно одним пробелом, последним словом является ″*″. Во второй строке вводится слово
W, в третьей строке вводится слово T. Количество символов в каждой строке не
превышает 1000. Все символы имеют коды от 32 до 254.

Output
Нужно выдать на стандартное устройство вывода полученную строку.

`Sample Input`

```
Hello world lord *
world
my
```

`Sample Output`

```
Hello world my lord *
```

Мой код:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char s[1000], w[1000], t[1000] , n[1000];
    int i,d1,d2,d3,d,j,v,dop;
    v = 0;
    d1 = 0;
    d2 = 0;
    d3 = 0;
    j = 0;
    d = 0;
    while ((s[d1]=getchar()) != '\n') d1++;
    while ((w[d2] = getchar()) != '\n') d2++;
    while ((t[d3] = getchar()) != '\n') d3++;
    for (i = 0; i < d1; i++) {
        d = 0;
        j = 0;
        if (s[i] != w[j]);
        else {
            v = i;
            dop = i + d2;
            for (; i < dop; i++)
                if (s[i] == w[j]) { d++; j++; }
                else break;
        }
        if (d == d2) break;
    }
        d = d + v + 1;
        j = 0;
        for (i = d; i < d1; i++)
        {
            n[j] = s[i];
            j++;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < d; i++)
            printf("%c", s[i]);
        for (i=0; i <d3; i++)
            printf("%c", t[i]);
        printf(" ");
        for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
            printf("%c", n[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Набирает 88 из 100. ПОЖАЛУЙСТА, найдите такие входные данные, при которых код не работает.

Comment: Вы лучше дайте URL проверялки :) Я бы, например, действовал не так, но хочу убедиться в правильности своего способа, прежде чем рекомендовать его...

Comment: К сожалению этого не могу сделать. Сайт для студентов.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror edit.c
>
> $ echo -e "aa a *\na\nb\n" | ./a.out 
> aab  a *
> ```

Ожидаемый ответ `aa a b *`.

Словами: вы сопоставляете слово с любым суффиксом слов во фразе. Это ошибка. Вторая ошибка - неверная печать.

***NB** Код трудно читать - он написан непривычно, напоминает ассемблер, не C. Задача не самая простая, код желательно лучше структурировать.*

Можно попробовать не редактировать строки в памяти. Для этого придётся использовать возможности C на всю катушку.

Начинается всё с хитрого `scanf` чтобы в один присест прочитать и фразу и слова.

Слово будем искать вместе с обрамляющими пробелами: `" слово "`. Это чтобы не находить слова внутри других слов. Для этого и фразу и слово надо дополнить пробелами с обеих сторон.

Когда слово найдено, печать ведётся кусочками нужной длины. Сами строки в памяти не редактируются.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 1000

int main() {
    char d[LEN + 3] = {' '};
    char w[LEN + 3] = {' '};
    char t[LEN + 1];
    if (scanf("%[^\n] %s %s", d + 1, w + 1, t) != 3) {
        exit(1);
    }
    strcat(d, " ");
    strcat(w, " ");
    char *p = strstr(d, w);
    if (p == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
    char *q = p + strlen(w) - 1;
    printf("%.*s%s%.*s\n", (int)(q - d), d + 1, t, (int)(strlen(q) - 1), q);
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror edit.c 
>
> $ echo -e "aa a *\na\nb\n" | ./a.out 
> aa a b *
>
> $ echo -e "aa a c *\na\nb\n" | ./a.out 
> aa a b c *
>
> $ echo -e "aa a *\n*\nb\n" | ./a.out 
> aa a * b
>
> $ echo -e "a aa c *\na\nb\n" | ./a.out 
> a b aa c *
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, я бы делал примерно так:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char s[1001], w[1001], t[1001];
    fgets(s,1001,stdin);
    scanf("%s %s",w,t);
    char * c = strstr(s,w) + strlen(w);
    *c++ = 0;
        printf("%s %s %s",s,t,c);
}
```

Еще раз — *примерно*, потому что проверить негде. Может, там перед первым словом допускается пробел, или если после * есть пробел, то его тоже надо выводить. Вобщем, надо смотреть...

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо)